# what is CLASSPATH in make file

Tags: java, makefile

I just got a makefile like this

```
CLASSPATH=.:/usr/share/java/antlr.jar

Mipsim.class: Mipsim.java MipsimLexer.class MipsimLexerTokenTypes.class MipsimParser.class Memory.class Processor.class
    javac -classpath .:/usr/share/java/antlr.jar Mipsim.java

Memory.class: Memory.java MemoryAccessible.class
    javac Memory.java

Processor.class: Processor.java
    javac Processor.java

MemoryAccessible.class: MemoryAccessible.java
    javac MemoryAccessible.java

MipsimLexer.java MipsimLexerTokenTypes.java MipsimParser.java: Mipsim.g
    antlr Mipsim.g

MipsimLexerTokenTypes.class: MipsimLexerTokenTypes.java
    javac MipsimLexerTokenTypes.java

MipsimLexer.class: MipsimLexer.java
    javac MipsimLexer.java

MipsimParser.class: MipsimParser.java
    javac MipsimParser.java

clean:
    rm -f *.class MipsimLexer.* MipsimLexerTokenTypes.* MipsimParser.*
```

I have to run this make file, and build the object code. 
However, the terminal told this

```
  antlr Mipsim.g
  make: antlr: No such file or directory
  make: *** [MipsimLexer.java] Error 1
```

I guess probably anrlr.jar couldn't be found in this case. So I just changed the CLASSPATH into

```
CLASSPATH=.:/antlr.jar
```

and put antlr.jar in the same folder, then tried it again. The same error just happened again.....

Could somebody please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLASSPATH=.:/antlr.jar
```

That's not going to work. It says to use the current directory and the `antlr.jar` file in the *root* file system (which probably won't exist).

You may want to try:

```
CLASSPATH=.:./antlr.jar
```

And make sure that it exists for the duration of the `antlr` executable. Some `make` programs will execute each command in a separate shell so changing the `CLASSPATH` may not carry forward. I tend to use the `bash` "set variable for one process" method:

```
CLASSPATH=.:./antlr.jar antlr Mipsim.g
```

On top of that, the way you generally run `antlr` is by running java, giving the class you want to run, with something like:

```
java -cp ./antlr.jar org.antlr.Tool Mipsim.g
```

If you have an *executable* file (or script) `antlr` which will do that for you, it appears not to be in your path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried as your way. I put these source files Mipsim.java, MipsimLexer.class, MipsimLexerTokenTypes.class, MipsimParser, make file and antlr.jar together in the same directory, and cd into the directory, run the makefile.The same error message poped up again.....

Comment: You have to `export` the variable.  Just defining a variable in a makefile does _not_ export it to the programs (like `java`) that make invokes.  Use `export CLASSPATH := ...`